# Schedule Trigger by Updating?

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, campaign

If I have a trigger that runs on Campaign update. Can I schedule it by writing a batch that just updates all Campaigns? Or do I need to reproduce the logic of the trigger in the batch itself.

IE can I do this?

```
global class CampaignInfluence_BatchUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id FROM Campaign';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Campaign> campaigns_to_update) {
        update campaigns_to_update;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}
}
```

Or do I need to replace the 'update campaigns_to_update' with the logic of the update trigger?

And then to schedule:

```
global class CampaignInfluence_Scheduler implements Schedulable{
    global void execute (SchedulableContext SC){
       CampaignInfluence_BatchUpdate b1 = new  CampaignInfluence_BatchUpdate();
       database.executeBatch(b1);
       string sch = '0 30 2,6,10,14,18,22 * * ?';
       system.schedule('Batch', sch, new CampaignInfluence_Scheduler());
    }
}
```

Comment: well worth reading Separation of Concerns https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Separation_of_Concerns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger only fires on update of Campaign, so the only way to cause it to fire is by updating the campaign records you want it to act on. If you include the logic of your trigger in your batch class, you'd be duplicating the actions of your trigger, which would fire again following the batch class. Would you want the trigger to fire again? If not, then don't include the logic from your trigger in your batch class, but make certain you include the conditions sufficient to cause your trigger to do what you want it to on the records included in the batch.

Comment: Thanks, I think that makes sense. I would only want it to fire once so it sounds like I can leave the logic in the trigger and just call the mass update.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the trigger is doing something after the update or unrelated directly to the insertion (e.g. no .addErrors), you could (and should) re-structure the trigger and use a Trigger Handler pattern that calls a utility method to process the Campaign updates.  Then you can call that utility method anywhere else you need to (e.g. controllers, extensions, batch, scheduled apex, queueable apex, etc) by passing it a set of Campaign records.